Does Resizing, an overlapped partition used to be accessed via a windows system prior linux installation using GParted, Safe?
Summary of my Story
I am trying to install bodhi linux on a low end ASPIRE one mini laptop. Some things happened during partitioning disk spaces using window's defragmentor. I ended up deleting all necessary system files (just for some extra space) and then installed linux. One day i try booting into windows (cause why not!) and i end up at grub rescue.
To fix that i live booted using the same os and mounted my sda1, sda2, sda3, and sda5 (i previously installed linux in an extention of sda4 which i do not remember the name of) to backup any data i can.
This is the partition:
Device      |    Boot |   Start     |      End     |     Sectors    |    Size  |   Id  |    Type        |
/dev/sda1   |         |   2048      |   206847     |     204800     |   100M   |   7   |  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT   |
/dev/sda2   |     *   |  206848     |   96258047   |     96051200   |   45.8G  |   7   |  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT   |
/dev/sda3   |         | 96258048    |   187527167  |     91269120   |   43.5G  |   7   |  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT   |
/dev/sda4   |         | 187529214   |   204802047  |     17272834   |   8.2G   |   5   |  Extended          |
/dev/sda5   |         | 204802048   |   488394751  |     283592704  |   135.2G |   7   |  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT   |

I successfully backed up sda2. I headed towards installing linux on sda2 or sda4 and when i chose the option to manually reformat a partition, i am shown only one partition which is '/dev/sda'.
Then i made another partition in desperation sda6 out of sda4.
Then i opened GParted and it prompted a Libparted Error saying "cant have overlapping partitions"
I selected "Ignore" then got prompted another one saying "Cant have a logical partition outside of the extended partion on /dev/sda."
I selected "Ignore" again. After that both of the windows repeated themeselves one more time before prompting me to the UI.
Where to my surprise i see an extra unallocated 135.23 GiB partition besides '/dev/sda5' which is also 135.23 GiB. I pulled out info on both:
sda5:- {filesystem=ntfs, Status = mounted on /mnt/sda5, Path=/dev/sda5, First Sector=204802048, Last Sector=488394751, Total Sectors=283592704}
unallocated:- {filesystem=unallocated, Status = N/A, Path=unallocated, First Sector=204802048, Last Sector=488397167, Total Sectors=283595120}

Also i pulled info for sda4 and sda6 this is what i found:
sda4:- {filesystem=unallocated, Status = N/A, Path=unallocated, Used Space=N/A ,First Sector=187529214, Last Sector=187531263, Total Sectors=2050}

sda6:- {filesystem=ext4, Status = Not mounted, Path=/dev/sda6, Used Space=108.73MiB, First Sector=187531264, Last Sector=204799999, Total Sectors=17268736}

Appareantly sda4 is the one causing "Cant have a logical partition outside of the extended partion on /dev/sda." error. And sda5 is being overlapped and causing "cant have overlapping partitions" error.
Now i am deciding on weather to risk my sda5 and Delete the conflicting unallocated space (appears as an extra 135.23 GiB partition) in GParted. This space overlaps with '/dev/sda5', and then resize '/dev/sda5' to ensure it uses the full space without overlapping. What would be the risk factors involved in here? What should i look out for?
I can backup only some of my important data but it would be great to know in advance
SOME ADDITIONAL INFO
this is what lsblk gave:
NAME     MAJ:MIN     RM  SIZE       RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda        8:0       0   232.96G    0   disk  
├─sda1     8:1       0   100M       0   part     /mnt/sda1
├─sda2     8:2       0   45.86G     0   part     /mnt/sda2
├─sda3     8:3       0   43.56G     0   part     /mnt/sda3
├─sda4     8:4       0   1K         0   part  
└─sda5     8:5       0   135.26G    0   part     /mnt/sda5
└─sda6     8:6       0    8.26G     0   part  

....and this is what df -h gave:
Filesystem                                Size    Used   Avail   Use%    Mounted on
tmpfs                                     196M    6.2M   190M    4%      /run
/dev/sdb1                                 1.3G    1.3G    0      100%    /cdrom
/cow                                      977M    28M    950M    3%      /
/dev/disk/by-label/writable               136M    2.8M    13G    1%      /var/log
tmpfs                                     977M    0      977M    0%      /dev/shm
tmpfs                                     5.0M    4.0K   5.0M    1%      /run/lock
tmpfs                                     977M    8.0K   977M    1%      /tmp
tmpfs                                     196M    32K    196M    1%      /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1                                 100M    9.8M   91M     10%     /mnt/sda1
/dev/sda2                                 46G       27G  19G     59%     /mnt/sda2
/dev/sda3                                 44G       44G  27M     100%    /mnt/sda3
/dev/sda5                                 1366G    135G  1.1G    100%    /mnt/sda5

excuse my inexperience i am new to linux stuff.

bhodi linux is not supported on AskUbuntu.

You have old MBR(msdos) partitioning. Since Microsoft required UEFI with gpt back in 2012, few systems have the very old MBR partitions. The extended partition is a container for all logical partitions starting with sda5 & above. MBR has a limit of 4 primary partitions including the extended partition. If using gpt, the limit is 128 primary partitions, but user can even add more if required ( never seen a question on that.).

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.
